# Using Kerberos authentication with Paramiko

Tags: python, kerberos, paramiko

I'm struggling to figure out how to use kerberos authentication with python and paramiko. I've found the documentation for paramiko but don't know how to implement it and there seems to be a lack of tutorials specifically for kerberos and paramiko since its so new.

When I ssh outside of python for normal usage, I insert a smart card and type the following from the command line in OSX Mavericks...

```
$ kshell
$ pkinit
```

...which then prompts me for my pin number associated with the card. From there I get a kerberos ticket and can ssh to the server.

I've used paramiko in the past but without kerberos... The following code is an example of what I've tried, but I get errors and can't connect.

```
import paramiko
import gssapi

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(hostname = 'my.server.name',
        username = 'user.name',
        gss_auth = True,
        gss_kex = True)
```

Comment: Please give more details on how your Kerberos authentication is implemented (see http://serverfault.com/questions/329901/how-does-kerberos-work-with-ssh for an example). Specifically, who should obtain a TGT (i.e. initially authenticate you to Kerberos)?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev The post now reflects the method for authentication

Comment: It's still unclear if you wish your program to obtain TGT for you or are happy to keep doing it yourself as you currently do.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, I wish to obtain the TGT manually (i.e. enter the credentials myself for security reasons) but have the code take those credentials and manage ssh operations. Is this possible? Is it recommended to let the code do it for me?

Comment: What I dug up on the topic is pretty much the same you printed. If you cleared all the requirements and are still getting errors, elaborate on them. There are e.g. hints that in OSX, you need to set some environment variables for `python-gssapi` to find you system's Kerberos-related files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [How does Kerberos work with SSH?](https://serverfault.com/questions/329901/how-does-kerberos-work-with-ssh) says, Kerberos authentication in SSH is essentially some custom data transfer instead of regular authentication (that includes getting a ticket from KDC) if the server reports `gssapi-with-mic` in available authentication mechanisms.

Support for it `paramiko` has been committed in 09.2014 in [pull request 267](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/267) and is available from `v1.15` onwards.

To use it,

1. See [Installing docs](http://www.paramiko.org/installing.html#optional-dependencies-for-gss-api-sspi-kerberos) for additional requirements
2. use `gss_auth` parameter of [`SSHClient.connect`](http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/1.15/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect). `gss_kex` is optional to authenticate the server using Kerberos as well rather than its SSH key.